# Is there a way to clean up assemblies that I have ngen'd in mass

Tags: ngen

I have added a whole bunch of assemblies to test something. I added them 1 assembly at a time. I need to clean up the assemblies that I added and I am wondering if there is a way to do that in mass. The only way that I know of is to do "ngen uninstall "

Is there another quicker way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching I wasn't able to find a way to do this. I just looped through all of the and did a ngen uninstall.